# Cron not working sometimes after installed module

Tags: magento-1.9

we set up cron job as below . it was working until we installed module to send Abandoned cart emails.

[image]

when we run **http://sitename.com:81/cron.php**, we get error as :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTemplate() on a non-object in
```

`$tpl = $this->getDesign()->getTemplate();`

**function** , full code : http://pastebin.com/gewZSRrp

```
public function getProcessedTemplate($variables = null)
    {
        $tpl = $this->getDesign()->getTemplate();

        $result = $this->_render($tpl, $variables);

        if ($this->getDesign()->getTemplateType() == Extension_EmailDesign_Model_Design::TEMPLATE_TYPE_HTML) {
            $result = Mage::helper('emaildesign')->styleHtml($result);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

**Edit**

```
public function getDesign()
    {
        if ($this->_design == null && $this->getDesignId()) {
            $this->_design = Mage::getModel('emaildesign/design')->load($this->getDesignId());
        }

        return $this->_design;
    }
```

**Edit 2**

sometimes below result

[image]

sometimes below result :

[image]

Strange is [link : http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cron.php](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/cron.php) will show above Fatal error sometimes and no error after some times. But no abandoned cart email is sent.....

Comment: there is nothing called `getDesignId()` in your code thats why `$this->getDesign()` returns `Null`

Comment: @GopalPatel please check updated question or full file code here : http://pastebin.com/gewZSRrp

Comment: I go through that code already thats why I am saying it returns null and you are trying to call `->getTemplate();` on null

Comment: @GopalPatel Thanks a lot for your time and help, i need your support like this in upcoming days also.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending emails, we are creating **Templates** and we are creating **Triggers** and assign that template to Triggers.

We deleted some triggers, that is the reason cron didt worked,

**Solution** : Deleting all those "scheduled Mails" from database will help to run cron job again.