# Time difference in backend and Database

Tags: magento-1.9

we are creating new row in DB table when user click on button & we are saving product related informations with **created date**.

[image]

[image]

```
protected function _createProduct() 
{
 $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);
$emaildate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$data = array('product_id'=>$product->getId(),
        'customer_id'=> $customerId , 'created_at' => $emaildate);
$model = Mage::getModel('example/mydesign')->setData($data);
```

}

full function : http://pastebin.com/LuMhy7K9

**Issue** :  in **backend** time is showing **5:30 hours** ahead than time present in **DB table**.

our site [IST] timings is 5:30 hours ahead than GMT

Comment: You can set Timezone in  System > Configuration > General > Locale Options to **India Standard Time (Asia/Calcutta)**

Comment: @JaiminSutariya thanks for reply , i checked there, its set `IST` only, also this is happening only for time present in this table, for other tables in magento , everything is fine......

Comment: I had an issue with date something like this before. To understand what time your Magento database is using, you can use this extension. 
 https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

This is not relating to what you need, but it helps you to find the time that is using in databse. Check the time when cron will get executed. After that set your timezone  in System > Configuration > General > Locale Options.

Comment: @LedianHymetllari Thanks , i installed `Aoe scheduler` , right now `cron jobs` are not working in site as i installed custom module.... i explained issue here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165735/cron-not-working-sometimes-after-installed-module

Comment: @BabyinMagento can you try that ` date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));`

Comment: @LedianHymetllari I updated your code and i will get result after 5 minutes as it requires `cron job` to display in backend...

Comment: @L sorry for delay, i tried your code , but still same result....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Magento's `gmtDate` function to get date and save it to db table.

```
{
    $product->setCreatedByCustomerId($customerId);
    $emaildate = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $data = array('product_id'=>$product->getId(),
            'customer_id'=> $customerId , 'created_at' => $emaildate);
    $model = Mage::getModel('example/mydesign')->setData($data);
}
```

Comment: I updated your code and i will get result after 5 minutes as it requires `cron job` to display in backend...

Comment: sorry for delay, i tried your code , now in Database table, time is showing 5:30 hours behind, but in backend its displaying current [correct]  time....